# C# - swagger inserting values and passing array of strings to Linq shows NULL instead of the values inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, api, swagger

In Swagger I insert some values and I want to pass an array of strings, containing those values, to Linq. (the ids are strings in this case). If I pass a simple string, not an array, it works to insert one value. But I need to pass an array of values.

Here's a link built by the API when trying to insert 2 values (it looks weird for an array): http://localhost:port/api/Members?ids=97882831302&ids=97882831308

The problem is that the array **shows NULL** instead of the values inserted. And I get the following error:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'System.String[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive
>   types are supported in this context."

[image]

```
public class MembersController : ApiController
    {
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllMembersByIdentifiers(string[] ids) {
                using (sampleEntities entities = new sampleEntities()){
                    var numbers = entities.tblmembers
                        .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.identify)  ).ToList();

                    if (numbers != null)
                    {
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, numbers);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Member with id: " + ids + " not found");
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`[FromUri]` did the fix in my case. Collection parameter type can be `IEnumerable<...>`.

It's confusing that other parameters are filled correctly from a URL by default - which IMO should also happen to collection parameters as it's a get request.

You could check whether the parameters are passed by inspecting `Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri`.

With `[FromUri]`:

[image: with FromUri]

Without `[FromUri]`:

[image: without FromUri]

Answer (score 0):

o think you've 2 problems in your code ..

FIRST:

pass data with , like:

```
98989794, //<---
4343545345
```

SECOND:

in your C# can i suggest to you to check for string null or empty like:

```
 public class MembersController : ApiController
 {
     [HttpGet]
     [Route("api/Members/Find/{ids}")]
     public HttpResponseMessage FindMemebers([FromUri]string[] ids) {
        // CHECK THE ARRAY NOT EMPTY
        if(!ids.Any() || ids.All(xx=> string.isNullOrEmpty(xx))
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "empty params");

        using (sampleEntities entities = new sampleEntities()){
            var numbers = entities.tblmembers
                .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.identify)  ).ToList();

            if (numbers != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, numbers);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Member with id: " + ids + " not found");
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It seems there's a ")" missing in the 1st "if" line. Also it says that the "BadRequest()" does not work (it says it cannot convert to HttpResponse). Si I replaced it with "CreateErrorResponse". I also tried to insert values in Swagger with comma "," and without (in Swagger says to insert values on each line - no mention of comma). I still get an error: '"ExceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException"'

Comment: Ah sorry ... just try to call your method GET ( or put a [Route] decoration) and [HttpGet] verbs decoration) ... and try to set ([FromUri]string[] ids) cause i think it aspect it as QUERYSTRING PARAMS at the moment

Comment: Can u please share code how to do that? I tried `[Route][HttpGet]public HttpResponseMessage GetAllMembersByIdentifiers(string[] ids) {...` . The `BadRequest()` is still underlined with red. I don't know exactly what u mean to "call your method GET"... If it's rename it GET, I tried and  `BadRequest()` is still underlined.

Comment: Nope, not even showing the service for MembersController anymore. So I commented out the new lines. But I observed something interesting though. The link built by the api looks like weird for an array I guess: http://localhost:port/api/Members?ids=97882831302&ids=97882831308

Comment: maybe it's better to send it in POST ..and wrap it in a object instead a simple string[]

Answer (score -1):

What solved it was:

1. adding `[FromUri]` hinted by @federico-scamuzzi
2. replacing `string[]` with `List<string>`.

So in the code looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage FindMemebers([FromUri]List<string> ids) { ...
```