# How can I pass an array of Guid via Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

When I make a post -> engines, I always get an empty Guid.

```
 [HttpPost]  
    public HttpResponseMessage Start([FromUri] Guid[] engines){
}
```

I am trying via swagger to put engines as parameter like this: 
["9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482"] and 
[9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482]

I found out what i did wrong
In swagger i need to provide multiple values in new lines:
so the parameters need to look like this:
9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482
9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482

[my post request via swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50QdJ.png)

Comment: We need more details. What have you tried to populate the engines, how could we re-create the example "https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve". Did you pass the array of guid in the body of the request?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43805874/34092 help?

Answer (score 1):

If you repeat a query string parameter the data will interpret as an array. You could craft your request like this (correcting the URI of course) :

```
/api/home?engines=4d000b1f-058b-42ad-8242-b1389a21d195&amp;engines=4d000b1f-058b-42ad-8242-b1389a21d195&amp;engines=....etc
```

Comment: but how I can do it via swagger?

Comment: I know what swagger is, but I don't know how to use/configure it. If you can't figure it out then you may do better to create a class with a property of type `Guid[]` and have your controller receive an object of that type - though you would probably put the data in the body instead of the URI.